# upgrade El Capitan to High Sierra -> Elixir does not work

Tags: elixir, macos-high-sierra

After upgrading to Mac OS High Sierra, Elixir did no longer work while giving an error mentioning 'BoringSSL' errors.

npm fora could not give further information except stating erlang had an error ...

Comment: What the flakiness of some operating systems has to do with [tag:elixir]?

Comment: Plz give your information about Elixir version, Erlang version.

Comment: $ elixir -v
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Elixir 1.5.3 => This was after upgrading elixir, so i can't tell you what version i had before

Comment: @mudasobwa, it seems that apple made a decision somewhere with dropping OpenSSL, this gives some mismatches with BoringSSL that is being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the error with the following steps

- Update Xcode to version 9+

command line commands

- brew update
- brew upgrade erlang
- brew upgrade elixir

( not mentioning pulling hair and others )

( I added this as a solution here since a lot of my colleagues had this error too after upgrading )

Comment: Yup. High Sierra now favors BoringSSL so Erlang and friends need to be patched. An update homebrew will include the patches.